# How can I leave completion mode keeping the completion result in a binding when there's no popup?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

Currently:

- I have some key binding `A` → `^X^O` (in insert mode) to omni-complete something
- I have some key binding `B` → `^Ogj` to temporarily do something in normal mode (in this case, move down a display line)

However, if I press ^A^B, the second ^O conflicts with the first ^O and removes the omnicompletion.

How can I modify ^A so that it exits the ^X mode?

For normal typing I'd just use `<esc>gj` but this is in a binding.

---

*I did read help for `i_CTRL-X` and `ins-completion`, but I can't find any dedicated key. `popupmenu-keys` (^Y) only work when there's a popupmenu, in this case there isn't because there's only one completion entry.*

*I did find some workaround (posted as an answer below), but I may have missed some dedicated method to do it. (like ^Y in completion mode with popup)*

<sub>*For context, I'm typing </**^X^O** to omni-complete HTML tags.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The second `^O` actually functions like `^N` when omnicompletion is active. From `:h i^x^o`, we see that

> CTRL-O  or
> CTRL-N :        Use the next match.  This match replaces the previous one.

To exit omnicompletion, we need a key that "does nothing", as suggested by your answer. One such combination is `^gU` (This actually prevents a break in the undo sequence when used with `<left>`,`<right>`).

Thus the following mappings will work:

```
inoremap ^A ^X^O^GU
inoremap ^B ^Ogj
```

(where `^X` is entered by pressing <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>CTRL-X</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

These are some workaround:

- `<space><backspace>`. Works (space is guaranteed to exit the completion mode), but doesn't seem very nice.
- `<left><right>`. Should work, as long as the expansion does not expand to nothing.
- `<c-g><c-g>`. This is no-op by now, but I think the behavior is not documented.

  - The above, and map `<c-g><c-g>` to `<nop>`. *Does not work*.
- `<c-\><c-o>i`.